# At my home, when enabling DHCP gives me a default gateway. At my workplace, enabling DHCP gives me no default gateway. Why is that?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, routing, dhcp

I'm setting up a local dicom connection at my home and it all works fine when there is a default gateway between computers. But at my workplace its not working. I need to set computers at my workplace to static with a default gateway. But where do I find their default gateway exactly? Because when I set computers at DHCP, to check their default gateway, all computers there have no default gateway when they are at DHCP.

Comment: When using DHCP, look at the IP address assigned.  Copy the first 3 segments and use "1" for the last.  Like 10.0.1.1 or 192.168.1.1.  This is probably (not certainly) what your gateway is.

Comment: I think you should check the dicom device with the suggestion above (if you're not talking about a microscope, never mind). Can you add another network card, or use a virtual solution? It kind of sounds like setting one might affect what you can connect to at work. Also, can you specify your OS?

Comment: DHCP is a protocol for configuring endpoints (the computer you are enabling DHCP on).  It requires a DHCP server that is provided all of the details for how the endpoints need to be configured to function correctly.  One of these details is the default gateway, and another is how to assign IP addresses on the network.  If you don't have a DHCP server, the DHCP clients will typically timeout their requests for information and automatically configure an IP address starting with 169.x.y.z, with no gateway.

Comment: What makes you think there is a default gateway? It’s not required for basic networking. Internet access could be restricted to require a proxy server. This is quite common in company networks. // DHCP servers can be set up to not provide a default gateway (DHCP option 3). // Also note that a default gateway is not _between computers_ on the local network segment.

Comment: Thank you all guys for commenting. I'm slowly figuring out what you guys mean. So their setup is really different from our home network. And that #1, is that, they might not have a DHCP server. and #2 is that, they might have a DHCP but it's configured to not provide a default gateway. Now the abstracting concept for me now is "A default gateway is not between computers on the local network segment." How can that be? Ain't the default gateway the I.P. of the router? Where computers are all connected on?

Comment: And dicom viewers and servers are using port numbers to send on. And they need to forward their ports, if they are not connected on the same router.

Answer (score 0):

The manager of a network may (or MAY NOT) run a DHCP server on that network.  If that manager does run a DHCP server, that DHCP server may (or MAY NOT) be configured to provide a default gateway to one or more computers on that network.

A default gateway is pretty much required for Internet access, BUT many types of communication are possible with no routers ("gateways") at all, as long as the hosts (computers on the network) have compatible IP addresses and netmasks, or use some other networking protocol(s) that doesn't require IP.

So it sounds as though the DHCP server at your work is either set to provide nothing to your computer (your computer might configure itself with a 169.x.y.z address when it stops waiting for DHCP), or it may be configured to provide some information, but no default gateway, to your computer.

Note that the DHCP server can make decisions on what configuration to provide your computer based on a variety of information, including the MAC address of your network card.  Perhaps (since it is a workplace), the network manager has the DHCP server set up not to automatically configure new or unrecognized computers.